# Is there a Linux image wich was compiled with -mfloat-abi=softfp?

Tags: operating-systems, linux

I'm trying to find an OS that was compiled with `-mfloat-abi=softfp` to be able to use my precompiled ARM binaries on my Raspberry. Although I understand the reason why Raspbian and Arch are compiled with `hard`, I'd like to give it a try and compare the performance.

Is there such a distribution/image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Arch Linux

At this stage (`archlinuxarm-13-06-2012.img`), Arch uses soft float ABI (`softfp`). You'd better grab an image quick, because it will start using hard float soon.

Comment: That's interesting since yesterday they told me on IRC that it's a hard float image... OK, thanks, I'll give it a try...

Comment: I haven't got my Pi to hand Once you've burnt the Arch image, you should be able to find out with it is hard or soft. `uname -a` maybe?

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try...

Comment: or `gcc -v`, Arch definitely works with soft float

Comment: yeah, I've also tested the binaries, at least the `archlinuxarm-13-06-2012.img` image is `softfp`

Comment: @Scolytus Who told you on which irc channel?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain don't remember who, I don't have a log, but it was on #archlinux at freenode

Comment: @Scolytus #archlinux-arm is a better channel (for ARM stuff)

Answer (score 4):

## Debian, Arch and other images.

You can still download the old debian wheezy image from the official raspberry pi download mirror. Debian wheezy image is 100% sure softfloat, because it is the official arm port of debian.

There exists no official link to it, but you can find it in the index of the mirror.

http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/images/

http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/images/debian/7/

Comment: good to know... Would be nice if they would keep the links on the page...